# Lost bit in reading from serial port

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I'm trying to read data from custom hardware using serial port. I believe the configuration was right. The problem is, I see some of the byte is missing. In the data, length of the data is specified, so I know if some of the data were missing.

My configuration is as follows :

```
int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)
{
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0) return -1;

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // raw input
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;                    // read does block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;                    // 0 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl (flow control)

    //disable hw flow control
    #ifdef CRTSCTS
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    #endif
    #ifdef CNEW_RTSCTS
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CNEW_RTSCTS;
    #endif

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);        // ignore modem controls,
                                            // enable reading

    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(ISTRIP | IGNCR | INLCR | ICRNL
        #ifdef IUCLC
             | IUCLC
        #endif
    );
    tty.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST
        #ifdef ONLCR
             | ONLCR
        #endif
        #ifdef OCRNL
             | OCRNL
        #endif
        #ifdef ONOCR
             | ONOCR
        #endif
        #ifdef ONLRET
             | ONLRET
        #endif
    );

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

this is how I read it :

```
int fd = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK);
char buf [10];
while(1) {
   int n = 0;
   while (n = read (fd, buf, sizeof buf) > 0) {
       write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n); //this printing
       .. other job ..
   }
}
```

below is the example of data :

```
// correct data
#*69880001000800010007003F4530302403322402FE24080524000024012C2400142430303030302452B4FF

// example of lost data (lost data is signed by _ )
#*69880001000800010007003F4530302403322402FE2408092_000_24012C240014243030303030241674FF
#*69880001000800010007003F4530302403312402FF24080524_00024012C240014243030303030244EF9FF
```

For the configuration, What I'll need is : 
baud rate : 19200
data bits : 8
stop bits : 1
parity : none
flow control : none

FYI, my hardware is sending data byte-per-byte. So *n* in the code above is always 1 (or 0).

When I try using putty, everything is okay. Is there something I missed?

Thank you

Comment: What language are you working on? Put in in tags

Comment: Not an answer to the question, however, each time I had problems with serial port it was due to bad settings. My tip: double check your port setting. Check if it does not translate some char combination like '\r\n' into another, etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: 1) Show the ".... read and try to print 'buf' and ..." part. 2) Change to `char buf [100];` 3) Setup looks OK 4) Verify `n` is not `< 0`